# PXE boot failing on RHEL install; PXE-E79

Tags: linux, redhat, installation, pxe-boot, uefi

i'm trying to install RHEL 9.0 on a gigabyte motherboard, Product Name: H170M-D3H-CF.  My dhcp setup has worked in the past, so I don't think the dhcp is the issue.  I know that **something** is going between the dhcp server (also the kickstart server) because I did have a typo in the dhcpd.conf file and have fixed it.  The error changes to the following:

`PXE-E79 NBP is too big to fit in free base memory`

Elsewhere I read that the problem is the client is trying to use BIOS boot when it should be doing UEFI boot.  (ahh, the machine previously had a UEFI disk, and that's what I want to use going forward.  Thus, "BIOS" is to be avoided.)  The suggestion is to turn off "legacy" boot.  I can't find a way to do that in my motherboard's, ahem!, BIOS.  (should it be called BIOS or something else?)

I've used this kickstart server for a long time; I believe the tftp, dhcp, http parts are all okay.  I've installed RH 8.5 on at least two machines with this.

UPDATE:
looks like i don't have enough debug information to chase this problem down.  the motherboard is (i guess) set up to use UEFI only, but that's not happening, and there's no indication of why.  so my next idea is to resort to the old pxeboot.  while (1) sigh();
oh, well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Motherboards can boot in Legacy (BIOS) mode or UEFI mode.
You must force your motherboard to boot in UEFI mode by setting that in your Motherboard setup screen.
When you do this the Motherboard will be ready to take and boot an UEFI NBP (network boot Program) usually 2-3 MB

If your Motherboard is currently set to boot in Legacy mode it'll expect to load a BIOS NBP which is 300KB or so.

If your Motherboard is very old and only works in BIOS mode you won't be able to boot it in UEFI mode